# Open Safari from Prototype Cell in new Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have a tableview in a ViewController defined in storyboard. the tableview has prototype cells. i want that when user touches the cell then a url should open in  external safari of iphone. how to achieve that?
from where i have to invoke the following line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:siteURL]];
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of UITableView before asking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class of which an instance is set to the table view's delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:siteURL]];
}
```

Comment: But i am using storyboard. is this the standard approach? pls suggest.

Comment: @SubhenduKumarMukherjee Yes. And btw until you are not knowledgable enough to create a complete UI from code only, you should not be using storyboards yet.